# Why is my button.enabled not showing as true in my code?

Tags: c#, button, boolean

I have this problem with changing the value of `myButton1.Enabled` to `true`. I go to use the value of that buttons enabledness to set `myButton2.Enabled` to the same value as `myButton1.Enabled`.

```
public void MyMethod()
{
    myButton1.Enabled = true;
    myButton2.Enabled = myButton1.Enabled;
}
```

As I step through the code using the debugger `myButton1.Enabled` doesn't change to `true` therefore `myButton2.Enabled` doesn't change to `true` but then when `MyMethod()` finishes, `myButton1` is enabled and I can click it but `myButton2` is not enabled. I am just interested in if anyone knows why this is happening because logically it should work.

Just to clarify I am not looking for a workaround as I already have that, I only want to know why this didn't work and any way to fix it.

Thanks!

Comment: What kind of Visual Studio are you using ? and your OS ? Because your codes works perfectly in my system (Win10 VS2015). Clean project with only 2 buttons.

Comment: Redraw or Refresh required? I believe it needs to be an event, so update is done properly

Comment: @x... I have Windows 7 and am using VS2010. This is a medium sized project and is not worth my time to create a clean project for something so small. But as I said I'm just trying to understand why this line `myButton1.Enabled = true;` does not set the enabled property of the button from `false` to `true`. Thanks for the reply

Comment: @kurakura88 I have tried putting both of those in between the two lines and neither had any success. Thanks for the reply

Answer (score 0):

Check your properties for the button. If your `enabled` is put to `false` in your properties, eventhough you wrote `myButton1.Enabled = true;`, it will still be `false`

Comment: Enabled was set to `false` in the properties so I changed it to `true` and it is still acting the same. Thanks for the reply

Comment: are you sure the debugging point is correct? when i tested it, i have no problem with it. try putting the point on myButton1.Enabled = true and step into from there.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put `Application.DoEvents();` between the two and see if that changes.

Comment: I tried that and it didn't change anything. Thanks for the reply

Comment: Never ever suggest `Application.DoEvents()`. It is never a good answer.